# “A person who always pays their debts late” VS “Someone who always pays their debts on time”

Tags: word-request, idioms, expressions, slang

I was wondering if there is any word / idiom / expression to define someone who borrows money from relatives and friends and **pays them always late**.

I know the words:

- [Deadbeat](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/deadbeat)
- [Welcher](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/welcher)

But they tend to indicate someone does not want to pay back at all, while I need an adjective etc. which is used to imply that they pay back, but just (a bit late =/= on time.)

Also, I am looking for the antonymous word / expression which is used to define **someone who always pays his debts on time.**

**Example:**

> - I won’t even lend Sam a penny! He’s a / an.......... 
>   However, I’ll give my whole life to his sister. She’s a truly reliable person; although she’s jobless now, but if she borrows you can rest assured that no matter how, she’ll pay you back. Everybody knows that she’s a/an............

Comment: I don't really recommend it, because it is too obscure, but there is a borrowing from Yiddish:  "mensch" meaning a "a person of integrity or rectitude; a person who is morally just, honest, or honourable, compassionate and virtuous".  It is too culturally specific to be of use to a learner, if you don't say "oy vey" then you'll sound odd using "mensch", But it is one of those Yiddish words that would be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of casual phrases:

> She's a class act.

> She's a brick.

This one suggests that she is completely dependable.

In more formal English, I think you have to say

> She's completely dependable.

> Her integrity is unquestionable.

There doesn't seem to be a convenient noun.  I mentioned "Mensch" in a comment. But this slang is not common outside of the Jewish community (it is borrowed from Yiddish)

Comment: Thank you @James K. well, then may I ask you whether as you mentioned “dependable” and as (I think “reliable” too) can define a person who pays his/her debts always on time, then the adjectives “unreliable” and “undependable” can introduce a person who always pays late?

Answer (score -1):

For the extremely scrupulous person I like the description "You could take their handshake to the bank and it'd draw interest".